# Process Substitution - difference between less than and greater than

Tags: linux, bash

In [Process Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) what is the difference between `>(command_list)` and `<(command_list)` as both return a file name stored in `/dev/fd`?

Comment: This question would be much more appropriate in [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com) (or possibly [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  the  >(list)  form  is  used,  writing to the file will provide input for list and if the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.
Hope this will help.